# Database Index vs Primary Key

Tags: database, sqlite, indexing

I want to start off saying I am not a database guru, but I'm decent with the basics.

I have a set of IO data that I'm storing in two tables which are uniquely identified by 'ioid' and 'machinenum'.

I have a 2 tables: IOConfig which uniquely identifies points (all the identifying information and a primary key: ConfigID). And a data table that contains samples of these items.

My table layouts below are to test using a primary key + index versus using just an index, so I know there is duplicate data.

Think of IOConfig table as such:

```
ConfigId(PK)   machineNum   ioId   ioType
```

Think of IOData table as such:

```
Timestamp      ConfigId     machineNum     ioId    value
```

If I use the ConfigID primary key, with an index on (timestamp,ConfigId) my query is like this:

```
select * from AnalogInput
where sampleTimestamp>=1520306916007000000 and sampleTimestamp<=1520351489939000000
  and configId in (1112)
```

```
"0" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE IOData USING INDEX cfgIndexAnalogInput (configId=? AND sampleTimestamp>? AND sampleTimestamp<?)"
```

If I avoid using ConfigID the query is like this:

```
select * from AnalogInput
where sampleTimestamp>=1520306916007000000 and sampleTimestamp<=1520351489939000000
and ioId in (1)
and machineid=1111
```

```
"0" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE IOData USING INDEX tsIndexAnalogInput (sampleTimestamp>? AND sampleTimestamp<?)"
```

Why wouldn't I get the improvement that I see with the first query + Index of (timestamp,configid) for the second query using an index of (timestamp,machineNum,ioid)? I ask because machineNum and ioid are used to define what point is unique to make a configId primary key... so one would expect them to equate?

schema:

```
CREATE TABLE 'IOData'(
    'sampleTimestamp' INTEGER,
    'configId' INTEGER,
    'machineId' INTEGER,
    'ioId' INTEGER,
    'value' REAL);

CREATE TABLE 'IOConfig'(
    'sampleTimestamp' INTEGER,
    'configId' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    'machineId' INTEGER,
    'ioId' INTEGER,
    'ioType' INTEGER);

CREATE INDEX `Something` ON `IOData` (`sampleTimestamp` ASC,`machineId` ASC,`ioId` ASC)

CREATE INDEX cfgIndexAnalogInput ON IOData(configId,sampleTimestamp)

CREATE INDEX tsIndexAnalogInput ON IOData(sampleTimestamp)
```

Comment: As you wrote, PK is unique, index no. So PK has less calculation then Index. SQLite is also not so heavy optimized, so maybe also the tripple column index are not really so fast.

Comment: I see no improvement via the triple column index. I was hoping there was something more advanced, a way to virtually link machineNum, ioid into a virtual PK and index with timestamp. Reason I ask is the off the shelf Database recorder I have won't allow me to add new columns like ConfigId and I'm trying to find a way to improve it. Using configID is a custom recorder app that I wrote. Much improved but hoping I can somehow still use the off the shelf one.

Comment: Show the actual table definitions, and the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for both queries.

Comment: @CL. I added the data you requested. So the query is not using the new index. Any idea why it would take another simple index over the one I made specifically for this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) to understand how indexes work, and [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) to see what specific optimization will be applied.

In this case, the filter on `sampleTimestamp` uses inequality comparisons, so, according to [section 1.0](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#where_clause), that must be the last column in the index (either in an explicit index, or in a three-column primary key):

```
CREATE INDEX SomethingBetter ON IOData(machineId, ioId, sampleTimestamp);
```